# Can git understand this {path1,path2,...} syntax?

Tags: bash, git

I can do `ls -l ../lib/boto/{route53,ec2,beanstalk,mturk}` in Bash and it produces results as expected.

However if I do

```
$ git rm -r ../lib/boto/{route53,ec2,beanstalk,mturk}
```

I get

```
fatal: pathspec '../lib/boto/ec2' did not match any files
```

Does `git` understand this path syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `set -x` and then repeat the command. The first thing you will see should be the actual command you're running. Example:

```
$ set -x
$ ls -l ../lib/boto/{route53,ec2,beanstalk,mturk}
+ ls --color=auto -l ../lib/boto/route53 ../lib/boto/ec2 ../lib/boto/beanstalk ../lib/boto/mturk
(actual output here, omitted)
$ set +x     # to revert
```

It shows my `ls` got `--color=auto` (because of `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` I happen to have) but never got these braces (`{what,ever}`). They were expanded by Bash, this is called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).

> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated. This mechanism is similar to filename expansion, but the filenames generated need not exist.

Note that brace expansion has nothing to do with paths. It operates on arbitrary strings and doesn't care if the result can be interpreted as a path to existing object or a path at all.

Your `git` line behaves basically like my `ls` line. Assuming no alias interfered, you actually run

```
git rm -r ../lib/boto/route53 ../lib/boto/ec2 ../lib/boto/beanstalk ../lib/boto/mturk
```

> Does `git` understand this path syntax?

Irrelevant. It may or may not treat `foo{bar,baz}` specially; but even if it does, your shell expands it first and braces never get to `git` (unless you quote them, you didn't).